# How to place values from html inputs into a javascript array of objects

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object

I have three inputs which will be given by the user and i want these 3 inputs to make up objects in an array in my javascript file, i.e, the values for these 3 inputs will make up each object in thearray, everytime the user inputs the 3 values and clicks enter, a new object with those 3 values as properties should be added into the array. How do i achieve this?

I have tried to get the values, and onclick to push them into the array but i keep get a "Cannot access 'arr_items' before initialization
    at addName"

```js
let input2 = document.getElementById("itemName");
let input3 = document.getElementById("itemWeight");
let input4 = document.getElementById("itemValue");
const arr_items = [];
let i = 0;

function addValues() {
  arr_items[i].name.push(input2.value);
  arr_items[i].weight.push(input3.value);
  arr_items[i].value.push(input4.value);
  i++;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Items Information:</p>
  <input id="itemName" type="text" placeholder="enter item name">
  <button onclick="addValues()" id="name">Enter</button>
  <input id="itemWeight" type="number" placeholder="enter item weight(kg)">
  <input id="itemValue" type="number" placeholder="enter item value">
</div>
```

I expect everytime the user inputs the 3 values and clicks enter, a new object with those 3 values as properties should be added into the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were doing it wrongly try this:

```js
      const arrayItems = new Array();

      function addValues(){
        let input2 = document.getElementById("itemName");
        let input3 = document.getElementById("itemWeight");
        let input4 = document.getElementById("itemValue");
        let inputs = {
            input1 : input2.value,
            input3 : input3.value,
            input4 : input4.value
        }
        
        arrayItems.push(inputs);
        console.log(arrayItems);
      }
```

```html
<div>
    <p>Items Information:</p>
    <input id="itemName" type="text" placeholder="enter item name">
    <input id="itemWeight" type="number" placeholder="enter item weight(kg)">
    <input id="itemValue" type="number" placeholder="enter item value">
    <button onclick="addValues()" id="name">Enter</button>
</div>
```

Comment: ggreat, can you assist me with this https://stackoverflow.com/q/55876351/11250543

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call the property `name`, `weight` etc on the array element using `.`. This is wrong. Try do:

```js
let input2 = document.getElementById("itemName");
let input3 = document.getElementById("itemWeight");
let input4 = document.getElementById("itemValue");

const arr_items = [];
let i = 0;

function addValues() {
  arr_items[i] = {
    name: input2.value,
    weight: input3.value,
    value: input4.value
  };

  i++;
  console.log(arr_items)
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Items Information:</p>
  <input id="itemName" type="text" placeholder="enter item name">
  <button onclick="addValues()" id="name">Enter</button>
  <input id="itemWeight" type="number" placeholder="enter item weight(kg)">
  <input id="itemValue" type="number" placeholder="enter item value">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two main aspects to note in the answer. One is that the array should be declared as a variable (not a constant), the other is that you should move the input var code into the function.

I added an alert so that you can see the outcome (wasn't sure if you wanted to allow them to be added without weight etc? This would cause confusion in your storage/retrieval of data.. so I moved the enter button)

Hope this helps

```js
var arr_items = [];
function addValues() {

  let input2 = document.getElementById("itemName");
  let input3 = document.getElementById("itemWeight");
  let input4 = document.getElementById("itemValue");

  var item2 = input2.value + " " + input3.value + " " + input4.value;
  arr_items.push(item2);
  alert( [arr_items]);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Items Information:</p>
  <input id="itemName" type="text" name="item" placeholder="enter item name">
  <input id="itemWeight" type="number" name="item" placeholder="enter item weight(kg)">
  <input id="itemValue" type="number" name="item" placeholder="enter item value">
  <button id="name" onclick="addValues()">Enter</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Regarding the storage/retrieval, you can see from the other answer that if you add only a name, and then the same name with weight etc, you have 2 records then; the first is not overwritten by the second. That's what I meant by confusion..

Comment: thank you for your answer but according to your code, the item 2 variable added to the array is not an object. That is what i am trying to achieve. The array is supposed to contain objects with properties of name,weight and value which it gets from the user inputs.

Comment: @dClint it does just that. I moved the declaration of the array outside the function (that was my bad) - and ran entered multiple values. The array is just that - an array!

Answer (score 0):

You can just push to array again and again without counter. Like so:

```
let input2 = document.getElementById("itemName");
let input3 = document.getElementById("itemWeight");
let input4 = document.getElementById("itemValue");

const arr_items = [];

function addValues() {
  arr_items.push({name: input2.value, weight: input3.value, value: input4.value});
  console.log(arr_items);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small chunk of code, that I stripped down, that takes every input field, within a parent, that has a `name` attribute and uses those `name` attribute values as the keys in an object.

If uses the `value` of the input fields as the values in the object.

This allows the output object to change based on which input fields are in the parent element. If the input element does not have a `name` then it is not included.

This code can be reused and it always hands back the object needed.

```js
const getEls = srcEl => {
  const subs = [...srcEl.querySelectorAll('[name]')];
  return subs.reduce((acc, sub) => {
    acc[sub.getAttribute('name')] = sub.value;
    sub.value = '';
    return acc;
  }, {});
  
  subs[0].focus();
}

let results = [];

function doIt() {
  const srcEl = document.getElementById('container');
  const values = getEls(srcEl);
  results.push(values);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(values,0,20));
}

const btn = document.getElementById('submit');
btn.addEventListener('click', doIt);

const resultsBtn = document.getElementById('show');
resultsBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(results,0,2));
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p>Items Information:</p>
  <input id="itemName" name="name" type="text" placeholder="enter item name"/><br/>
  <input id="itemWeight" name="weight" type="number" placeholder="enter item weight(kg)"/><br/>
  <input id="itemValue" name="value" type="number" placeholder="enter item value"/><br/>
  <button id="submit">Enter</button>
  <hr/>
  <button id="show">Results</button>
</div>
```