# How to get buttons to disable after a condition has been met?

Tags: javascript, html

From the code in my previous question, i now have a function "knapsack" that is supposed to disable the buttons when the total weight(tot_weight) is greater than or equal to the maximum weight("max_weight"). I need it to disable all the "add" buttons when the condition is met.(this will cause no more input to be accepted when max capacity is reached)

My code does not work correctly, it justs disable the last button after only selecting one item (i dont think it checks the condition).

```js
arr_items = new Array();
    knap = new Array();
        let input = document.getElementById("userinput");
        let input2 = document.getElementById("itemName");
        let input3 = document.getElementById("itemWeight");
        let input4 = document.getElementById("itemValue");
        let ul = document.getElementById("list");
        let ul2 = document.getElementById("knap")
        let listCount = 0; 
let myfunction2;
        let knapsack;
  let  max_weight;
     myfunction2 = () =>{ 
        input.value = "";
}
    let inputLength=() => input2.value.length;
    let addValues = () =>{
        
         inputs = {
            name : input2.value,
            weight : parseFloat(input3.value),
            value : parseInt(input4.value)
        }

        arr_items.push(inputs);
        console.log(arr_items);
createListElement();
myfunction2();
}
let createListElement = () => {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input2.value));
    ul.appendChild(li);
    input2.value = "";
    input3.value = "";
    input4.value = "";

    let btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Add"));
    li.appendChild(btn);
    btn.className = "butt";
    btn.id = listCount; 
    btn.onclick = addTo;
    listCount++; // increment the list count variable
    console.log(input.value);
    max_weight = input.value;

     knapsack = (max_weight,knap)=>{
    let tot_weight = 0;

    for(i=0; i<knap.length;i++){
        tot_weight = knap[i].weight + tot_weight;
    }
    console.log(tot_weight);
    console.log(max_weight);
    if (tot_weight >= max_weight){
        btn.disabled = true;
    }
}


}
function addTo(){
    var li2 = document.createElement("li");
    var id = parseInt(this.id); // retrieve the id of the button
    li2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arr_items[id].name));
    ul2.appendChild(li2);
    knap.push(arr_items[id]); //use the id of the button to select array to push to knap from the array item
    console.log(knap);
    knapsack(max_weight,knap);
}

let addListAfterClick = () =>{
    if (inputLength() > 0) {
        addValues();
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>KnapSack</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <h1>KnapSack</h1>
<div>
 <input id="userinput" type="number" placeholder="Enter Capacity">
</div><br>
<div>
 <p>Items Information:</p>
 <input id="itemName" type="text" placeholder="enter item name">
 <input id="itemWeight" type="number" placeholder="enter item weight(kg)">
 <input id="itemValue" type="number" placeholder="enter item value">
 <button onclick="addListAfterClick()" id="value">Enter</button>
</div>
 <ul id="list">LIST OF 20 ITEMS TO CHOOSE FROM
 </ul>
 <ul id="knap"> LIST OF ITEMS IN KNAPSACK
 </ul>
<div>
 <button onclick="myFunction()" id="done">Done</button>
</div>
<p id="demo"></p>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what's the `max_weight`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code `max_weight` is being reset every time the "Add" button is clicked, this might make the condition to disable the "Add" buttons behave abnormally.

To disable all the buttons, you have to get all the buttons you created with the ClassName you assigned to them. Here is the modification of your code

```js
 arr_items = new Array();
    knap = new Array();
        let input = document.getElementById("userinput");
        let input2 = document.getElementById("itemName");
        let input3 = document.getElementById("itemWeight");
        let input4 = document.getElementById("itemValue");
        let ul = document.getElementById("list");
        let ul2 = document.getElementById("knap")
        let listCount = 0; 
let myfunction2;
        let knapsack;
  let  max_weight;
  let tot_weight = 0;
     myfunction2 = () =>{ 
        //input.value = ""; I had to comment this line out to avoid resetting max_weight value everytime the add button is click
        // since we need to evaluate it everytime
}
    let inputLength=() => input2.value.length;
    let addValues = () =>{
        
         inputs = {
            name : input2.value,
            weight : parseFloat(input3.value),
            value : parseInt(input4.value)
        }

        arr_items.push(inputs);
        console.log(arr_items);
createListElement();
myfunction2();
}
let createListElement = () => {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input2.value));
    ul.appendChild(li);
    input2.value = "";
    input3.value = "";
    input4.value = "";

    let btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Add"));
    li.appendChild(btn);
    btn.className = "butt";
    btn.id = listCount; 
    btn.onclick = addTo;
    listCount++; // increment the list count variable
    console.log(input.value);
    max_weight = input.value;

     knapsack = (max_weight,knap)=>{
    

    for(i=0; i<knap.length;i++){
        tot_weight = knap[i].weight + tot_weight;
    }
    console.log(tot_weight);
    console.log(max_weight);
    if (tot_weight >= max_weight){
        let buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("butt"); // get all the buttons
        for( let button of buttons){
            button.disabled = true; // disable all the buttons
        }
    }
}


}
function addTo(){
    var li2 = document.createElement("li");
    var id = parseInt(this.id); // retrieve the id of the button
    li2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arr_items[id].name));
    ul2.appendChild(li2);
    knap.push(arr_items[id]); //use the id of the button to select array to push to knap from the array item
    console.log(knap);
    knapsack(max_weight,knap);
}

let addListAfterClick = () =>{
    if (inputLength() > 0) {
        addValues();
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>KnapSack</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <h1>KnapSack</h1>
<div>
 <input id="userinput" type="number" placeholder="Enter Capacity">
</div><br>
<div>
 <p>Items Information:</p>
 <input id="itemName" type="text" placeholder="enter item name">
 <input id="itemWeight" type="number" placeholder="enter item weight(kg)">
 <input id="itemValue" type="number" placeholder="enter item value">
 <button onclick="addListAfterClick()" id="value">Enter</button>
</div>
 <ul id="list">LIST OF 20 ITEMS TO CHOOSE FROM
 </ul>
 <ul id="knap"> LIST OF ITEMS IN KNAPSACK
 </ul>
<div>
 <button onclick="myFunction()" id="done">Done</button>
</div>
<p id="demo"></p>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I think this should work as expected

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that in `createListElement()` you are only disabling the button you just created:

```
let btn = document.createElement("button");
...
if (tot_weight >= max_weight){
  btn.disabled = true;
}
```

What you want is for all buttons to be disabled, so you could do something like getting all buttons by className, and disabling them in a loop:

```
allButtons = document.getElementsByClassName( "butt" );
  if (tot_weight >= max_weight){
    for ( const button of allButtons ) {
      button.disabled = true;
  }
}
```

The conditional is definitely being checked every time. This should fix it.